# Trigger is Not Updating current Month Deatils?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a Table named `Table_Lookup` every week it was updated. So I have created 2 `triggers` on that table, if new records are inserted triggers fires and Inserts the New data in to another Table named as `Table_Lookup_Change`.

Note:I have data up to August in `Table_Lookup` but when trigger is fired it inserts data only up to July it is missing one month data. I am working from last 2 weeks I can't figure out the problem. Can you guys look in to My code please..

Comment: `on ... and A.FLMNet = B.FLMNet Where A.FLMNet is not null ... and B.FLMNet is null and A.FLMNet is not null` is an interesting construct. Tip: Use table aliases that help, e.g. `from deleted as d left join MediaFactor_Lookup_Change as MFLC`.

Comment: deleted as d left join MediaFactor_Lookup_Change B ...I Have already given alias B

Answer (score 0):

Your triggers have structure

```
if (exists(select 1 from deleted))
begin
   .
   .
end
else
begin
   .
   .
end
```

since you have `deleted` (the old values) and `insert` (the new values, included those that where modified via `UPDATE`).

what you need to do is something like

```
if (exists(select 1 from deleted))
begin
   .
   .
end

if (exists(select 1 
           from inserted 
           left join deleted on inserted.MediaFactor_ID = deleted.MediaFactor_ID
           where deleted.MediaFactor_ID
   )
begin
   /*update or insert as needed. filtering out those from deleted table*/

end
```

Comment: I cant get your answer can you please elebarate it .

Comment: I assume that you are new to triggers, have a look to some articles like [this](msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx), or just google for _SQL inserted deleted_ The execution of a `trigger` has two special tables, `inserted` and `deleted` new rows are in the inserted table, the new assigned values during updates are in the inserted table too. The original rows of updates and the deleted rows are in the deleted table. If you look into the triggers that you posted you'll see that you are already using thos tables.

Comment: Yes iam new to triggers i never used them i likely to work on UDF and Stored Proc.Can you give me a suggestion how to proceed in above trigger.

Comment: I'm finishing my day. Just google for `SQL triggers inserted deleted` you'll find tons of materials,  then look at your tiggers and you'll see that those tables aren't so scary.

Comment: Yes tables are not scary.But bug is scary :(

Answer (score 0):

if (exists(select 1 from deleted))
begin
   .
   .
end

if (exists(select 1 
           from inserted 
           left join deleted on inserted.MediaFactor_ID = deleted.MediaFactor_ID
           where  Where A.FLMNet is not null
                and B.Media is null
                and B.Year is null
                and B.Month is null
                and B.Factor is null
                and B.FLMNet is null
                and A.FLMNet is not null)
   )
begin
   /*update or insert as needed. filtering out those from deleted table*/

end